# How to break out of Jquery for iteration

Tags: jquery

I have a situation that I am using AJAX to call a page that returns a list of business locations to populate a Google map. My original goal was to display markers for locations whose radius touched the website visitor's location.

Now I only need to know IF the website visitor is within the radius of any one of the locations returned by the ajax call. In the code below, you see a conditional statement "fink <= rs.Records[recno].radius". What I am attempting to do is the first time that statement executes to true, set a cookie and/or call a function and exit the for loop.

As a side question, a friend told me of something called grep (I think). Do I need to loop through an entire list to find if that condition is true? Meaning I know in mySQL I can just query something like "select * from locations where radius < 50". So if my ajax returns 10,000 locations, all I need to know is my website visitor distance within the radius of any any of my locations?

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
  var p = 0.017453292519943295; // Math.PI / 180
  var c = Math.cos;
  var a = 0.5 - c((lat2 - lat1) * p) / 2 +
    c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) *
    (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p)) / 2;
  return .62137119 * (12742 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a))); // 2 * R; R = 6371 km
}


function getMarkers(lat, lng, city, state) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/getMarkers.asp?state=Nebraska',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text',
    error: function(xhr, status, errorstr) {
      console.log(errorstr); // just show error message in console if there was an error
    },
  }).done(function(response_obj) {
    console.log(response_obj);
    var rs = eval(response_obj);
    if (rs) { // has a non-null value
      var str = rs.RecordCount + " Users:<br/>";

      for (var recno = 0; recno < rs.RecordCount; recno++) {
        fink = distance(<%= session("uLat") %>, <%= session("uLng") %>, rs.Records[recno].latitude, rs.Records[recno].longitude);
        if (fink <= rs.Records[recno].radius) {
          $(".markers").append("<li data-center='" + rs.Records[recno].latitude + ", " + rs.Records[recno].longitude + "' data-locale='" + recno + "' data-radius='" + rs.Records[recno].radius + "' data-location='" + rs.Records[recno].city + "'>" + rs.Records[recno].street + "</li>\n");
        }
      }
      initMap();
    } else {
      str = "No users found"
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: `break` will break out of a loop.

Comment: *"set a cookie and/or call a function and exit the for loop."* i see where you called .append, but, i don't see where you tried setting a cookie and/or exiting the loop.

Comment: BTW, don't use `eval(response_obj)`, use `JSON.parse(response_obj)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `break;`

```
  for (var recno = 0; recno < rs.RecordCount; recno++) {
    fink = distance(<%= session("uLat") %>, <%= session("uLng") %>, rs.Records[recno].latitude, rs.Records[recno].longitude);
    if (fink <= rs.Records[recno].radius) {
      $(".markers").append("<li data-center='" + rs.Records[recno].latitude + ", " + rs.Records[recno].longitude + "' data-locale='" + recno + "' data-radius='" + rs.Records[recno].radius + "' data-location='" + rs.Records[recno].city + "'>" + rs.Records[recno].street + "</li>\n");
      break;
    }
  }
```

And if you want to know if any were found, you can set a variable.

```
  found_close = false;
  for (var recno = 0; recno < rs.RecordCount; recno++) {
    fink = distance(<%= session("uLat") %>, <%= session("uLng") %>, rs.Records[recno].latitude, rs.Records[recno].longitude);
    if (fink <= rs.Records[recno].radius) {
      $(".markers").append("<li data-center='" + rs.Records[recno].latitude + ", " + rs.Records[recno].longitude + "' data-locale='" + recno + "' data-radius='" + rs.Records[recno].radius + "' data-location='" + rs.Records[recno].city + "'>" + rs.Records[recno].street + "</li>\n");
      found_close = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!found_close) {
    // do something
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me. Seems that given a situation where you might have 10,000 locations, and maybe hitting true on 9,999, there would be a way to get a quicker answer than a loop. Have a great day.

Comment: You might be able to improve the database query, by calculating the distance there, then using `ORDER BY DISTANCE LIMIT 1`.